# Parsing an inconsistent json(different json structure for same API call) using Gson Library

Tags: android, json, gson

I am working on a Android app, where I have a web service call and that service returns me a Json Object as response but in some cases it is returning a different structure, please find the structure:

**Case 1: Json Structure**
The Json have keys called "from" and "to" which are of type String.

Ex:   "to": "BVRT",
      "from": "NS",

**Case 2: Json Structure**
The Json have keys called "from" and "to" which are of custom object.
ex:
      "from": {
        "name": "BANGALORE CY JN",
        "code": "SBC"
      },
      "to": {
        "name": "BHIMAVARAMTOWN",
        "code": "BVRT"
      },

As there is lot of nested objects I am using Gson Library to parse the json object which makes life easier instead of manual parsing.

**Issue Facing**
How do I construct my pojo class since there are two different structures for same api call,I have tried JsonIgnore but it didn't worked as it has the same json key in both the cases.

Please find the screenshot for better understanding which have the complete Json structure, hoping a reply with sample code snippet as this has been a blocker for which we could not proceed to further functionality of the app.[Json Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqIx3.png)

Comment: Please let me know the reason for down vote, If my question is wrong this are the API's given by railwayapi.com, which gives the different json structure for same API call

Comment: Use Object rather than String while parsing, manually do the logic by identifying the Object value

Comment: @HarshaVardhan I have even tried the approach you suggested but in order to check whether the result is string or custom object I need to use instancOf() but if it is String it will automatically maps, if it is custom object  it is unable to identify, and I I mentioned it is huge json with lot of relationships and need to maintain two forms of model object and how can I know which model object and how can I decide which version of model object to be used in order to display the results toUI, so I want to know if there is any other way which serve the puspose

Comment: If its a custom object, treatt the value as string and pass the string to Gson to convert a object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After research of few hours I got a solution for this, here my solution works without creating separate model classes to handle different Json structures for same API call:

**Model Class**

```
 public class TrainDetails {

    @SerializedName("to")
    private String toString;


    @SerializedName("from")
    private String fromString;


    @SerializedName("to")
    private ToStationPnrPojo fromStationObject;


    @SerializedName("from")
    private ToStationPnrPojo toStationObject;
}
```

Now construct a Gson object using ExclusionStrategy, here you can specify which fields you need to exclude in our model class in order to match the Json structure sent from server side.

```
try {
                JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(result);
                JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject.optJSONArray("train");
                if(jsonArray.length()>0){
                    JSONObject jsonObject1= jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                    Object test=jsonObject1.get("to");
                    if(test instanceof  String){
                        Log.e("Test","Instance OF String");
                        CustomExclusionStrategy ges = new CustomExclusionStrategy(TrainDetails.class, "toStationObject","fromStationObject");
                        gson= new GsonBuilder().setExclusionStrategies(new CustomExclusionStrategy[]{ges}).create();


                }else{
                        Log.e("Test","Instance OF Custom object");
                        CustomExclusionStrategy ges = new CustomExclusionStrategy(TrainDetails.class, "toString","fromString");
                        gson= new GsonBuilder().setExclusionStrategies(new CustomExclusionStrategy[]{ges}).create();

                }
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

We can pass the fields names to CustomeExclusionStrategy specifying Gson that exclude these fields while parsing the Json from server.

**CustomExclusionStrategy**

```
public class CustomExclusionStrategy implements ExclusionStrategy {
    private final List<String> _skipFields = new ArrayList<String>();
    private final Class<?> _clazz;


    public CustomExclusionStrategy(Class<?> clazz, String... fields) {
        _clazz = clazz;

        for (String field : fields) {
            _skipFields.add(field);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> clazz) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
        return f.getDeclaringClass() == _clazz
                && _skipFields.contains(f.getName());
    }
}
```

Hope this will be helpfull if any other were facing the similar issue while dealing with parsing of Json which is not in the client application control.